# Check if ReadDirectoryChanges works for given path

Tags: windows, delphi, networking, file-io, delphi-xe

Is there any way to test if `ReadDirectoryChanges` will work for a given path? (I assume that it won't work on Linux network shares for example). I guess that calling `ReadDirectoryChanges` on such a path will return an error code but I cannot test that currently. Anyone knows if that works? Any other ways to test it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Return Value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return
>   value is nonzero. For synchronous
>   calls, this means that the operation
>   succeeded. For asynchronous calls,
>   this indicates that the operation was
>   successfully queued.
>
> If the function fails, the return
>   value is zero. To get extended error
>   information, call GetLastError.
>
> If the network redirector or the
>   target file system does not support
>   this operation, the function fails
>   with **ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION**.

So just check for "ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION".

Answer (score 1):

If you want a blunt force test, monitor a directory, try and create a temporary file - if you dont get the response within a "reasonable" time frame. Assume that that folder cannot be tested.

Comment: Yes that's the solution I want to find a more elegant replacement for. Especially the timeout is very odd to assume as a constant. I don't know which internals affect the delay.